# Searching by several params at the same time Criteria Api

Tags: hibernate, jpa, search, dao, criteria-api

I have this code and it's working for only one word entering the input string. But I want to make a combined search. For example, I want to write family and name, and I want to have results with the persons, who have this name and family at the same time.

```
 @Override
    public List<Teacher> searchByString(String str) {

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Teacher> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Teacher.class);
        Root<Teacher> TeacherRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Teacher.class);

        Predicate predicateForName
                = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(TeacherRoot.get("name")), "%" + str.toLowerCase() + "%");

        Predicate predicateForFam
                = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(TeacherRoot.get("fam")), "%" + str.toLowerCase() + "%");

        Predicate predicateForOtch
                = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(TeacherRoot.get("otch")), "%" + str.toLowerCase() + "%");

        Predicate predicateForPhone
                = criteriaBuilder.like(TeacherRoot.get("phoneNumber"), "%" + str + "%");

        Predicate predicateForDate
                = criteriaBuilder.like(TeacherRoot.get("dateOfBirth").as(String.class), "%" + str + "%");

        Predicate predicateFinal = criteriaBuilder.or(
                predicateForName,
                predicateForFam,
                predicateForOtch,
                predicateForPhone,
                predicateForDate);

        criteriaQuery.where(predicateFinal);

        return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

    }
```

Sample data:

```
1   John Newman      London      8-999990999
2   John Malkovich   Paris    8-999995999
3   John NewMan      Moscow      8-999995999
```

Input string: John Newman

Result records:

```
1   John Newman   London   8-999990999
3   John NewMan   Moscow   8-999995999
```

Input string: John 5 (records with name John and having 5 in phone)

Result records:

```
2   John Malkovich   Paris    8-999995999
3   John NewMan      Moscow   8-999995999
```

Combination of queries can be different.

Answer (score 0):

Create searchCriteria class with specified string fields (name, etc..) then pass it to the searchByString method.

For example:

```
public List<Teacher> searchByString(SearchCriteria criteria)
```

Inside method add only not null predicates:

```
if(criteria.name != null) {
   //addPredicate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Input string = John 5(records with name John and having 5 in phone)**

Here predicates using your input looks like:

```
        Predicate predicateForName = criteriaBuilder.like(
             criteriaBuilder.lower(TeacherRoot.get("name")), 
             "%john 5%");

        //other predicates

        Predicate predicateForPhone = criteriaBuilder.like(
              TeacherRoot.get("phoneNumber"),
              "%John 5%");
```

You attempt to find records where `name like "%john 5%"` and `phoneNumber like "%John 5%"`.

You have to split input string into words and use predicates for every word.

```
public List<Teacher> searchByString(String str) {

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Teacher> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Teacher.class);
        Root<Teacher> TeacherRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Teacher.class);

        Predicate predicateFinal = getPredicateByInput(str, criteriaBuilder);

        criteriaQuery.where(predicateFinal);

        return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

}
```

---

```
public Predicate getPredicateByInput(String input, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        String[] words = input.split(" ");

        Predicate predicate = null;
        for(String word : words) {
          Predicate wordPredicate = getPredicateByWord(word, criteriaBuilder);

          if(predicate == null) 
              predicate = wordPredicate;
          else
              predicate = criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, wordPredicate);
        }

        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate, "Null predicate is not allowed. Invalid input string '" + input + "'");

        return predicate;
}
```

---

```
private Predicate getPredicateByWord(String word, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

    Predicate predicateForName = criteriaBuilder.like(
                      criteriaBuilder.lower(TeacherRoot.get("name")), 
                      "%" + word.toLowerCase() + "%");

    Predicate predicateForFam = criteriaBuilder.like(
                      criteriaBuilder.lower(TeacherRoot.get("fam")), 
                      "%" + word.toLowerCase() + "%");

    Predicate predicateForOtch = criteriaBuilder.like(
                      criteriaBuilder.lower(TeacherRoot.get("otch")), 
                      "%" + word.toLowerCase() + "%");

    Predicate predicateForPhone = criteriaBuilder.like(
                     TeacherRoot.get("phoneNumber"), 
                     "%" + word + "%");

    Predicate predicateForDate = criteriaBuilder.like(
                     TeacherRoot.get("dateOfBirth").as(String.class), 
                     "%" + word + "%");

    return criteriaBuilder.or(
                        predicateForName,
                        predicateForFam,
                        predicateForOtch,
                        predicateForPhone,
                        predicateForDate);
}
```

Like clause is heavyweight, so you should try to avoid redundant predicates